# cx_Freeze doesn't recognize modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, executable, python-3.6, cx-freeze

i'm using python 3.6, cx_Freeze 5.1.1.

I've made a code that makes wordcloud using this module:

[WordCloudGit](https://github.com/amueller/word_cloud)

I've placed it inside a PyQt5 UI as the following code shows:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from os import path
from wordcloud import WordCloud


class AppWindow(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.show()

class Ui_MainWindow(object):

currdir = 'C:\\Users\\lotem\\Desktop'

    def create_wordcloud(text):
          mask = np.array(Image.open(path.join(currdir, "cloud.png")))
          wc = WordCloud(background_color="white",
                   mask=mask,
                   max_words=200)

          wc.generate(text)
          wc.to_file(path.join(currdir, "wc.png"))


    def MakeWordCloud(self):
        text = self.textEdit.toPlainText()
        create_wordcloud(text)


    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(904, 675)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(217, 14, 85);")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")

        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.textEdit, 1, 0, 1, 3)

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Assistant Light")
        font.setPointSize(25)
        font.setBold(False)
        font.setWeight(50)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 1, 1, 1)

        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Assistant Light")
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 85, 127);\n"
                                      "color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 3, 2, 1, 1)

### Create word cloud button
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.MakeWordCloud)


        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.menuBar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menuBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 904, 31))
        self.menuBar.setObjectName("menuBar")
        self.menu = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menuBar)
        self.menu.setObjectName("menu")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menuBar)


        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)



    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "word cloud"))
        self.textEdit.setHtml(_translate("MainWindow", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:8pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p align=\"center\" style=\" margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\">type text</p></body></html>"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "<html><head/><body><p align=\"center\">word cloud</p></body></html>"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "create word cloud"))



app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QMainWindow()
ui = Ui_MainWindow()
ui.setupUi(window)
window.setWindowIcon(QIcon('cloudicon.png'))
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This program basically has a text box and a button, that when you click on it, it creates wordcloud using the module above.

The program works perfectly when i'm running it from PyCharm.

I've used cx_Freeze to make it an .exe program. When i click on the button to create the wordcloud in the .exe program, it stops working.

I think that the cx_Freeze doesn't import the WordCloud module. I've added it manually to the 'includes' in my setup.py file and even added every file from the module separately in 'include_files'. Both didn't work.

setup.py code:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import sys


base = None

if (sys.platform == "win32"):
    base = "Win32GUI"

additional_mods = ['numpy.core._methods', 'numpy.lib.format']
executables = [Executable("test.py", base=base)]

packages = ["idna", 'arabic_reshaper', 'pkg_resources', 'wordcloud', 'stop_words', 'numpy', 'bidi.algorithm', 'WordCloud']
options = {
    'build_exe': {

        'packages':packages,
         'includes':['numpy.core._methods', 'numpy.lib.format', 'arabic_reshaper', 'pkg_resources', 'wordcloud', 'WordCloud' ,
                     'stop_words', 'numpy', 'bidi.algorithm'],
        'include_files':[('C:\\Users\\lotem\\Desktop\\WordCloud\\cloud.png'),
                         ('C:\\Users\\lotem\\Desktop\\WordCloud\\Shoroq-Font.ttf'),
                         ('C:\\Users\\lotem\\Desktop\\WordCloud\\NewMainWin.py'),
                         ('C:\\Users\\lotem\\Desktop\\WordCloud\\WordCloudCode.py'),
                         ('C:\\Users\\lotem\\Desktop\\WordCloud\\cloudicon.png'),
                         ('C:\\Users\\lotem\\Desktop\\WordCloud\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\wordcloud\\__init__.py'),
                        ('C:\\Users\\lotem\\Desktop\\WordCloud\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\wordcloud\\color_from_image.py'),
                        ('C:\\Users\\lotem\\Desktop\\WordCloud\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\wordcloud\\DroidSansMono.ttf'),
                        ('C:\\Users\\lotem\\Desktop\\WordCloud\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\wordcloud\\query_integral_image.cp36-win32.pyd'),
                        ('C:\\Users\\lotem\\Desktop\\WordCloud\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\wordcloud\\stopwords'),
                        ('C:\\Users\\lotem\\Desktop\\WordCloud\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\wordcloud\\tokenization.py'),
                        ('C:\\Users\\lotem\\Desktop\\WordCloud\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\wordcloud\\wordcloud.py'),
                        ('C:\\Users\\lotem\\Desktop\\WordCloud\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\wordcloud\\wordcloud_cli.py'),
                         ('C:\\Users\\lotem\\Desktop\\WordCloud\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\wordcloud\\__pycache__\\__init__.cpython-36.pyc'),
                        ('C:\\Users\\lotem\\Desktop\\WordCloud\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\wordcloud\\__pycache__\\color_from_image.cpython-36.pyc'),
                        ('C:\\Users\\lotem\\Desktop\\WordCloud\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\wordcloud\\__pycache__\\tokenization.cpython-36.pyc'),
                        ('C:\\Users\\lotem\\Desktop\\WordCloud\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\wordcloud\\__pycache__\\wordcloud.cpython-36.pyc'),
                        ('C:\\Users\\lotem\\Desktop\\WordCloud\\venv\\Lib\\site-packages\\wordcloud\\__pycache__\\wordcloud_cli.cpython-36.pyc')
                         ]
    }

}

setup(
    name = "WordCloud",
    options = options,
    version = "1.0",
    description = 'Wordcloud',
    executables = executables
)
```

How do i make cx_Freeze import modules i've used in my code?

Thanks

Comment: i've copied the module folder from my general python site-packages folder into the dist folder that was created for the .exe program, and it worked out :)